# Can not find python boto3 batch_write response

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

The following code writes items into Dynamodb in batch:

```
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
  for item in chunk:   
   dynamodb_item = {
           'itemId': item['key'],
            'time': item['time'],
             'value': item['value']
                }                    
    batch.put_item( Item = dynamodb_item )
```

As stated in the following docs, if the batch call fails it returns the unprocessed items:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item

In boto3, how can I get the unprocessed items in the response?

How can I figure out if it's all handled successfully or if the call response has unprocessed items?

Comment: Did you try using `batch_write_item()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `batch_write_item` as you mentioned, instead of `put_item`

Check this [example](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiobotocore/blob/master/examples/dynamodb_batch_write.py):

```
response = await client.batch_write_item(
    RequestItems=request_items
)

if len(response['UnprocessedItems']) == 0:
    print('Wrote 25 items to dynamo')
else:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    unprocessed_items = response['UnprocessedItems']
    # proceed with unprocessed_items
```